# Couldn't connect to EC2 instance

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I'm trying to connect to my EC2 instance with terminal:

```
ssh -i server.cer ubuntu@ec2-**-**-***-**.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com
```

but have

> The authenticity of host 'ec2-**-**-***-***.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com (**.**.**.**)' can't be established.
>
> ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:*************************.
>
> Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?
>
> Host key verification failed

I couldn't connect to it with EC2 Instance Connect (browser-based SSH connection), but can do this with Filezilla.

If this matters I've deleted known_hosts file and made a new one.

Comment: Did you try to answer "yes" to the question `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])? ` ?

Comment: @SorenA, yes, it solves, thanks. I've been pressing enter before

Comment: Great, please acknowledge my answer below then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to answer "yes" to the question `Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no/[fingerprint])?` that ssh asks.